# bash screenshot script and writing url to file

Tags: python, bash, stdout

This is my code:

```
    #!/bin/bash
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M:%S`
import -window root "$HOME/Desktop/1.png"
python imgur.py > "$HOME/Desktop/tekst.txt"
mv "$HOME/Desktop/1.png" "$HOME/Desktop/screenshot $DATE.png"
```

It works when I run script from console. But I've also binded key.When I press it, everything is ok, except for text.txt. It's empty. Any ideas?

Comment: It's python script. It uploads file from desktop.

Comment: As I said, when I press Prt Scr button, it creates a new file tekst.txt, but it's empty. If I run script from terminal, it works perfectly ;)

Answer (score 1):

This bash isn't writing to "text.txt" on the desktop but instead to "tekst.txt". Is it that you're checking the wrong file?

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer I think. Though if you are correct it would be an answer but I'd also probably vote the question closed for a typo at that point.

Comment: Sorry I'm new enough that it wouldn't allow me to make this a comment.

Comment: I think it's reasonable to expect this to be the answer, given `text.txt. It's empty`. And users with 1 rep can't comment, so perfectly ok to answer in this case. Welcome to the site.

Comment: @BroSlow Indeed, I think may very well be the right answer. My point was more the latter half. That, in that case, my feeling would be that that's a close vote instead of a question that needs an answer.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't notice (nor did I remember that restriction even if I had noticed) the rep. Welcome.